# Jquery will display all the lightboxes on the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've made a simple Lightbox that will pop up and the image will be shown , but when it comes to PHP things get wired.It opens all my div's that have the class lightbox in it.

Javascript:

```
$('.lightbox').click(function(){
$('.spate').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 1000 , 'linear');
$('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 1000 , 'linear');
$('.spate, .box').css('display','block');
});
$('.inchide').click(function(){
$('.spate, .box').animate({'opacity':'.0'}, 500 , 'linear', function(){
$('.spate, .box').css('display','none');
});  
});
$('.spate').click(function(){
$('.spate, .box').animate({'opacity':'.0'}, 500 , 'linear', function(){
$('.spate, .box').css('display','none');
});
});
```

PHP/HTML:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query){
$post_image= $row['post_image'];
<?php if(!$post_image=="") echo '
<a class="lightbox" href="#"><img src="img/'.$post_image.'"></a>
<div class="spate"></div>
<div class="box"><div class="inchide">X</div> <img src="img/'.$post_image.'"></div>
';
}
```

The problem is when i have more than 1 image on the page,if one of the images is clicked a lightbox will appear for all images in particular.I can't get it to open the lightbox just for the clicked image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query){
$post_image= $row['post_image'];
<?php if(!$post_image=="") echo '
<div> <!--add all of that in div for each one-->
<a class="lightbox" href="#"><img src="img/'.$post_image.'"></a>
<div class="spate"></div>
<div class="box"><div class="inchide">X</div> <img src="img/'.$post_image.'"></div>
<div>
';
}
```

and use it like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lightbox').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.spate').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 1000 , 'linear');
    $(this).parent().find('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 1000 , 'linear');
    $(this).parent().find('.spate, .box').css('display','block');
    });
    $('.inchide').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.spate, .box').animate({'opacity':'.0'}, 500 , 'linear', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.spate, .box').css('display','none');
    });  
    });
    $('.spate').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.spate, .box').animate({'opacity':'.0'}, 500 , 'linear', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.spate, .box').css('display','none');
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx i forgot i have more than 1 class on the page because PHP creates a loop.

Comment: @camin10 never mind we always did that sometimes :).. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to select specific items not a class of items:

`$('.lightbox').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.spate').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 1000 , 'linear').css('display','block');
    $(this).next('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 1000 , 'linear').css('display','block');
});`